# NoReverseMatch error with Django

Tags: python, django

Keep getting this error: NoReverseMatch at /student/calendar.html  Reverse for 'view_event' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'event_title': u'Test'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['student/calendar/events/$']

Here are the relevant bits of the key files:

views.py:

```
def calendar_view(request):
   context = RequestContext(request)
   events = Event.objects.all()
   context_dict = {'monday': [], 'tuesday': [], 'wednesday': [], 'thursday': [], 'friday': [], 'saturday': [], 'sunday': []}
   for event in events:
        weekday = event.date.lower()
        if weekday in context_dict:
            context_dict[weekday].append(event)
    return render_to_response('polls/calendar.html', context_dict, context)

def view_event(request, event_title):
    event = Event.objects.filter(title = event_title)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html')
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^student/calendar', views.calendar_view, name='calendar'),
url(r'^student/calendar/events/$', views.view_event, name = 'view_event'),
```

calendar.html:

```
{% load tags %}


<table border="1">
<th>Monday</th>
<th>Tuesday</th>
<th>Wednesday</th>
<th>Thursday</th>
<th>Friday</th>
<th>Saturday</th>
<th>Sunday</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{%for event in tuesday%}
    <a href="{% url 'polls:view_event' event_title=event.title %}">{{ event.title }}, {{event.start_time}} - {{event.end_time}}</a></li> <br>
    {%endfor%} </td>
</tr>
```

detail.html:

```
   {{ event.title }}
```

The idea is that I have a database of events, and for each day of the week I have them put on the calendar. This part works. Now I am trying to add a possibility to click on any event to bring up a new page with detailed information (for now it's just the title). I followed some examples, but cannot get past this error...

Answer (score 1):

Your URL for the view_event view does not take any parameters. You'd need to have something like this:

```
url(r'^student/calendar/events/(?P<event_title>\w+)/$', views.view_event, name = 'view_event'),
```

Note that a title is not really suitable for using in a URL anyway, as it can presumably contain spaces. You should use a slug or a numeric ID.

Also note that your event_title view should use `Event.objects.get` not `filter`.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to automatically create a slug/id when an event is created?
Also, adding your line now results in this error: NoReverseMatch at /student/calendar.html

Reverse for 'view_event' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['student/calendar/events/(?P<event_title>\\w+)/$']

Comment: I fixed the problem, as the code had a stupid typo... However, it seems that when I click on the link for the event, it stays on the same page, only the url changes. What could be the reason?